# Unable to get Web API attribute routing enabled/working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have spent some considerable time trying to get Web API attribute routing working, and all I am getting are 404 errors no matter what I try.

I have a simple ApiController that tries to define a HttpGet at `api/hello/{number}` and `hello/{number}`:

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("api/hello/{number}")]
    [Route("hello/{number}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Hello> GetStuff(int number)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, number);
        return null;
    }

    [Route("api/hello")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostHello(Hello value) 
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, value);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I have this as my RouteConfig, enabling attribute routing:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

WebAPIConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my Application_Start() where I register the WebApiConfig:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

Does anyone see something I am missing?  I get 404 errors (unable to hit a breakpoint in GetStuff()) for all of the following:

- `http://localhost/api/hello`
- `http://localhost/api/hello/1`
- `http://localhost/hello`
- `http://localhost/hello/2`

My post does not work either.

Comment: Shouldn't the id in route config be changed to number >? and why would you receive any parameter for api/hello?

Comment: even if I remove the parameter, remove number completely, I still get 404 errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MVC routes are taking precedence over your API routes. Because you are using a catch all route for the MVC side (`"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`), and it is being registered first, your routing will always look for an mvc controller named `api` or `hello`, because that's the route it matched.

Try moving your api registration above your MVC route registration in your Global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
//then
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a route prefix at the class level. Then set the route at the function level.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/hello")]
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    [Route("getstuff/{number}")]
    public IEnumerable<Hello> GetStuff(int number)
    {
    }
}
```

Then call with `/api/hello/getstuff/1`